# Why my magento load each page in two steps?

Tags: magento

My magento website perform each frontend routing in two steps, for example when i request to http://example.com/test-product.html it will first load a blank page with magento favicon first then after just few seconds it will render the actual page. And the same story is for every page What's wrong is with magento?

Comment: That is not normal behaviour - at least I have never encountered it. Is it a plain Magento install? What version? Standard theme?

Comment: I think you have to reindexed your Catalog URL Rewrites and then check this again and also remove magento cache in var/cache folder

Comment: I agree with the comments above. Can you give more information? For example if you use your browser's developer tools you should be able to see what URL redirect is happening.

Comment: @VishalSharma thanks to you doing the same you said solved my problem. Why don't you post it as answer and i'll accept it for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to re indexed your Catalog URL Rewrites.

Go to the

```
System > Index Management
```

and then re indexed and also remove magento cache in var/cache folder